# how to insert data array to another array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

I want to check if the data is same then don't print the data but push that data to the first data.

for example I have data array like this:

```
0 => array:4 [▼
    "StartTime" => "00:00:00"
    "type" => 1
    "DateAppointment" => "2019-02-24"
    "SDay" => "Sun"
  ]
1 => array:4 [▼
    "StartTime" => "00:00:00"
    "type" => 1
    "DateAppointment" => "2019-02-25"
    "SDay" => "Mon"
  ]
2 => array:4 [▼
    "StartTime" => "00:00:00"
    "type" => 1
    "DateAppointment" => "2019-02-26"
    "SDay" => "Tue"
  ]
3 => array:4 [▼
    "StartTime" => "00:10:00"
    "type" => 1
    "DateAppointment" => "2019-02-24"
    "SDay" => "Sun"
  ]
```

data `array` 0, 1, 2 has the same StartTime, so I want my data to be like this

```
0 => array:10 [▼
    "StartTime" => "00:00:00"
    "type" => 1
    "DateAppointment" => "2019-02-24"
    "SDay" => "Sun"
    "type1" => 1
    "DateAppointment1" => "2019-02-25"
    "SDay1" => "Mon"
    "type2" => 1
    "DateAppointment2" => "2019-02-26"
    "SDay2" => "Tue"
  ]
1 => array:4 [▼
    "StartTime" => "00:10:00"
    "type" => 1
    "DateAppointment" => "2019-02-24"
    "SDay" => "Sun"
  ]
```

is that possible?

my script is like this

```
$interval = 10;
$hourMinInterval = 60 - $interval;
for ($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++){
    for ($j = 0; $j <= $hourMinInterval; $j+=$interval){

        $h = sprintf('%02d',$i);
        $m = sprintf('%02d',$j);
        $clock[] = $h.':'.$m.':00';

        if ($lastdate != 'lastsunday') {
            $timestampa = $lastdate;
        } else {
            $timestampa = strtotime('last Sunday');
        }

        for($ble=0;$ble<7;$ble++){
            $timeC = sprintf('%02d',$i).':'.sprintf('%02d',$j).':00';
            $tgla = strftime('%Y_%m_%d', $timestampa);
            $dateS = str_replace('_','-',$tgla);
            $sday = strftime('%a', $timestampa);
            $timeCs = array('StartTime'=>$timeC, 'type'=>1, 'DateAppointment'=>$dateS, 'SDay'=>$sday);
            $timestampa = strtotime('+1 day', $timestampa);

            if ($timeC == $timeCs['StartTime']) {
                $statusssss[] = $timeCs;
            }else{
                $statusssss[] = '';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have another way or any example with jsfiddle will be appreciated.

Comment: *IMO* it's bad idea to add some numbers to keys. Maybe better to convert them to arrays?

Comment: im not sure, i cant think another way, if u have any suggestion with example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
$arrayItems = [
    [
        "StartTime" => "00:00:00",
        "type" => 1,
        "DateAppointment" => "2019-02-24",
        "SDay" => "Sun"
    ],
    [
        "StartTime" => "00:00:00",
        "type" => 1,
        "DateAppointment" => "2019-02-25",
        "SDay" => "Mon",
    ],
    [
        "StartTime" => "00:00:00",
        "type" => 1,
        "DateAppointment" => "2019-02-26",
        "SDay" => "Tue"
    ],
    [
        "StartTime" => "00:10:00",
        "type" => 1,
        "DateAppointment" => "2019-02-24",
        "SDay" => "Sun"
    ]
];

$mergedArray = [];
foreach($arrayItems as $arrayItem) {
    $startTime = $arrayItem['StartTime'];
    unset($arrayItem['StartTime']);
    $mergedArray[$startTime][] = $arrayItem;
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($mergedArray);
```

**Result:**

```
array(2) {
  ["00:00:00"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["type"]=>
      int(1)
      ["DateAppointment"]=>
      string(10) "2019-02-24"
      ["SDay"]=>
      string(3) "Sun"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["type"]=>
      int(1)
      ["DateAppointment"]=>
      string(10) "2019-02-25"
      ["SDay"]=>
      string(3) "Mon"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["type"]=>
      int(1)
      ["DateAppointment"]=>
      string(10) "2019-02-26"
      ["SDay"]=>
      string(3) "Tue"
    }
  }
  ["00:10:00"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["type"]=>
      int(1)
      ["DateAppointment"]=>
      string(10) "2019-02-24"
      ["SDay"]=>
      string(3) "Sun"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *Try this* isn't considered the best of explanations of answers - please add something more meaningful!

Comment: "more meaningful".. about what ? How to `unset` array or how to add new elements to array ?

Comment: sorry but this is not like what i want, i want to group it, like what i say in the question.

Comment: This is exactly what you asked, grouping array with `StartTime`, if you want to access it inside your foreach loop, just use `foreach($arrayItems as $key => $value)`

Comment: yup, but i need the index and the `starttime`, cause i want to print it in my page. see my screenshot https://i.imgur.com/6ESDxGM.jpg

Comment: @Jazuly Check my answer ;)

Comment: @Jazuly check my comment above, `$key` is start time, and if you want index (I don't see need in it) just use increments, set `$i = 0;` before foreach loop, and increase it in the ending of loop, `$i++;` that's all

Answer (score 0):

This will give u the desired result!

```
$arrayItems = [
    [
        "StartTime" => "00:00:00",
        "type" => 1,
        "DateAppointment" => "2019-02-24",
        "SDay" => "Sun"
    ],
    [
        "StartTime" => "00:00:00",
        "type" => 1,
        "DateAppointment" => "2019-02-25",
        "SDay" => "Mon",
    ],
    [
        "StartTime" => "00:00:00",
        "type" => 1,
        "DateAppointment" => "2019-02-26",
        "SDay" => "Tue"
    ],
    [
        "StartTime" => "00:10:00",
        "type" => 1,
        "DateAppointment" => "2019-02-24",
        "SDay" => "Sun"
    ]
];

$mergedArray = [];
$i = 0;
foreach($arrayItems as $arrayItem) {
    $keys = array_keys($arrayItem);   
    foreach($keys as $key){

        if(array_key_exists($key, $mergedArray[$arrayItem["StartTime"]])){      
           $newkey = $key.$i;
           $mergedArray[$arrayItem["StartTime"]][$newkey] = $arrayItem[$key];
        }
        else{
           $mergedArray[$arrayItem["StartTime"]][$key] = $arrayItem[$key];                      
        }

    }
    $i++;
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($mergedArray);
```